# Laravel Paypal payment execute working on localhost but not on remote server

Tags: laravel, paypal, vuejs2

I am using laravel as a backend and vue as front end while integrating paypal. The integration works locally and the payment process works. But when I tried to go live, it give folowing errors

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.example.com/myApi/api/execute-payment/' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
>   POST https://www.example.com/myApi/api/execute-payment/ net::ERR_FAILED
>   Uncaught Error: Request to post https://www.example.com/myApi/api/execute-payment/ failed: [object ProgressEvent]. Correlation id: null
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhrError (http.js:123)**

I have already handled Cors on the backend. I have tried using Cors google extension on local server (hitting the live endpoints) but the execute payment method does not return to my url instead keep loading (executing and executing) which does not seem to stop.
I have not changed the paypal environemnt to 'production' on the client side though because of testing purpose.

Also the payment creation (createPayment) flow works fine on live server. It just gives this error after I login to paypal account and click pay (to start payment execution).

Kindly Help me. Thank you.

Comment: is your path is correct -https://www.example.com/myApi/api/api/execute-payment/

Comment: It is correct. I mistakenly added  two '/apis' here (which i have edited now) but it is correct in my code.@Hamelraj

Comment: add in your route file on top `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` `api.php or web.php`

Comment: Hi @Hamelraj. I have already made a CORS middleware to handle this cors issue and also it is not creating any issue while hitting create payment end point but does show this error after creating payment (when execute payment starts). And If  I add the recommended header in the api.php file. It gives : "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed." error even on the payment creation.